# Using PHP to create an image and add a logo to it

Tags: php, image, dynamic, generator

What I am trying to do is speed up some of the time building websites since we have such a large work load.  We tend to be doing the same things over and over, and for these Night Drop forms we have a small image preview below.  When clicked on it will open up the PDF, but I was wondering if there is a way to automate this so the image preview will automatically be created and just take the logo and re-size it and put it on the top like below.

Is this possible?  So it would start with the blank form on the left, and then take the logo.png file from the website and re-size it to the correct dimensions and put it in the top center like on the second image.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, just would be awesome if it could work!

Thanks :-)

[image]             [image]

Comment: Take a look on http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Assuming the one on the left was an image before the pdf preview you can look at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#composite before generating your pdf. regardless you can you use image magick to resize the logo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work!  Here is the code for anyone interested.

```
<?php
function resize($img, $w, $h, $newfilename) {

 //Check if GD extension is loaded
 if (!extension_loaded('gd') && !extension_loaded('gd2')) {
  trigger_error("GD is not loaded", E_USER_WARNING);
  return false;
 }

 //Get Image size info
 $imgInfo = getimagesize($img);
 switch ($imgInfo[2]) {
  case 1: $im = imagecreatefromgif($img); break;
  case 2: $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);  break;
  case 3: $im = imagecreatefrompng($img); break;
  default:  trigger_error('Unsupported filetype!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
 }

 //If image dimension is smaller, do not resize
 if ($imgInfo[0] <= $w && $imgInfo[1] <= $h) {
  $nHeight = $imgInfo[1];
  $nWidth = $imgInfo[0];
 }else{
                //yeah, resize it, but keep it proportional
  if ($w/$imgInfo[0] > $h/$imgInfo[1]) {
   $nWidth = $w;
   $nHeight = $imgInfo[1]*($w/$imgInfo[0]);
  }else{
   $nWidth = $imgInfo[0]*($h/$imgInfo[1]);
   $nHeight = $h;
  }
 }
 $nWidth = round($nWidth);
 $nHeight = round($nHeight);

 $newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);

 /* Check if this image is PNG or GIF, then set if Transparent*/  
 if(($imgInfo[2] == 1) OR ($imgInfo[2]==3)){
  imagealphablending($newImg, false);
  imagesavealpha($newImg,true);
  $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
  imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
 }
 imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $imgInfo[0], $imgInfo[1]);

 //Generate the file, and rename it to $newfilename
 switch ($imgInfo[2]) {
  case 1: imagegif($newImg,$newfilename); break;
  case 2: imagejpeg($newImg,$newfilename);  break;
  case 3: imagepng($newImg,$newfilename); break;
  default:  trigger_error('Failed resize image!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
 }

   return $newfilename;
}


$img = "images/logo.png"; // File image location
$newfilename = "images/dropoff_preview.png"; // New file name for thumb
$w = 45;
$h = 45;

$thumbnail = resize($img, $w, $h, $newfilename);


$image = @$HTTP_GET_VARS['image']; // Useful if using in an img tag to call images
$image = str_replace(array("/", ".."), "", $image); // Prevent abuse
$overlay = $thumbnail;

$dir = '';

// A default image for the demo...remove if you wish.
if ($image == NULL) {
    $image = 'images/dropoff_blank.jpg';
}

// Find if image exists
if (!file_exists($dir . $image)) {
    die("Image does not exist.");
}

// Set offset from bottom-right corner
$w_offset = 57;
$h_offset = 230;

$extension = strtolower(substr($image, strrpos($image, ".") + 1));

// Load image from file
switch ($extension)
{
    case 'jpg':
        $background = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir . $image);
        break;
    case 'jpeg':
        $background = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir . $image);
        break;
    case 'png':
        $background = imagecreatefrompng($dir . $image);
        break;
    case 'gif':
        $background = imagecreatefromgif($dir . $image);
        break;
    default:
        die("Image is of unsupported type.");
}

// Find base image size
$swidth = imagesx($background);
$sheight = imagesy($background);

// Turn on alpha blending
imagealphablending($background, true);

// Create overlay image
$overlay = imagecreatefrompng($dir . $overlay);

// Get the size of overlay
$owidth = imagesx($overlay);
$oheight = imagesy($overlay);

// Overlay watermark
imagecopy($background, $overlay, $swidth - $owidth - $w_offset, $sheight - $oheight - $h_offset, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight);

// Output header and final image
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=" . $image);
imagejpeg($background);

// Destroy the images
imagedestroy($background);
imagedestroy($overlay);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function doResizeAndWatermark () {

    $image = 'myImage.jpg';
    $watermarkImage = 'logo.png';
    $x = 10;
    $y = 10;
    $resizeWidth = '100';
    $resizeHeight = '200';
    $imagesize = getimagesize ( $image );
    $newImage = $image;
    if ( ! copy ( $image, $this->newImage ) )
        die ( 'Copy Image Failed' );

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $image );
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor ( $imagesize [ 0 ], $imagesize [ 1 ] );

    if ( ! imagecopyresampled ( $newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resizeWidth, $resizeHeight, $imagesize [ 0 ], $imagesize [ 1 ] ) ) {
        die ( 'Resizing Image Faild' );
    }
    $tmprslt = getimagesize ( $watermarkImage );

    $watermarkImageWidth = $tmprslt [ 0 ];
    $watermarkImageHeight = $tmprslt [ 1 ];
    $watermarkImage = imagecreatefrompng ( $watermarkImage );

    if ( ! imagecopyresampled ( $image, $watermarkImage, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermarkImageWidth, $watermarkImageWidth, $watermarkImageWidth, $watermarkImageHeight ) )
        die ( 'Watermark Copy Image Failed' );

    imagejpeg ( $newImage, $image, 85 );
}
```